# Virtualbox Bridge vs NAT (same setup, NAT works but bridge doesn't)

Tags: networking, virtualbox, centos

I installed CentOS 7 on a virtualbox machine.
When I set the network to NAT, `ping` gets packets back, `wget` gets pages and `yum` also works. 
 
However, if I shutdown the machine and set the network to Bridge, `ping` gets packets back but `wget` and `yum` hang.

I have the below set up in `/etc/sysconfig/nework-scripts/ifcfg-enp03` (but this file is not changed at all. Only the virtualbox setting for network is changed)

```
TYPE=Ethernet
BOOTPROTO=dhcp
NM_CONTROLLED=yes
ONBOOT=yes
NAME=enp0s3
DEVICE=enp0s3
...
```

EDIT (can't paste images yet): 
traceroute (NAT) 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/NbJ74.jpg

traceroute (bridge) 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/tYykb.jpg

Comment: What OS are your running on the host machine?

Comment: host OS is Windows 10

Comment: When you activate the bridged mode, make sure your VM's settings are set to replicate the state of the physical adapter. Also, have you tried a traceroute in your guest OS? Try: `traceroute 8.8.4.4` (It traces the route to Google.)

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue.

Problem host firewall was blocking the VM in Bridged mode.
Specifically Symantec Endpoint Security, I disabled network threat 
protection and everything started working under bridged mode.

Comment: hm.. I do recall I also had Symantec Endpoint Security. I cannot verify whether that would've solved my problem, but regardless, disabling the protection isn't the best option. (can't vote because of rep points yet, but definitely would've tried it out)